# How to implement AngularJS in ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have to use AngularJS and ES6 together and webpack as the building tool. Can anyone provide me a way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few resources that will be able to help you out.

- [Angular and ES6](https://www.sitepoint.com/writing-angularjs-apps-using-es6/)
- [Switching to ES6 with Angular](https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/switching-to-es6-with-angular-1-x-is-easy-a08c40c2fc72#.fl1irn865)
- [Style guide](https://github.com/orizens/angular-es6-styleguide)